# How to find Nakshatra and thithi using date

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I need to calculate [Nakshatra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakshatra) and [Thithi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tithi) using date-time and current location latitude and longitude.

Date from

```
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 // display in 12HR/24HR (i.e. 11:25PM or 23:25) format according to User Settings
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
    [dateFormatter release];
```

Longitude and latitude values from `NSLocationManager`. Can someone please shed light on the mathematical calculation?

Comment: This could be helpful..https://github.com/santhoshn/panchanga

Comment: there is no direct correlation and calculation is complicated.

Comment: you have to consider the following. 
Take one full-moon day as a reference.
solar year [earth's completes one rotation around sun] ~365 days. 
consider leap years. Now consider moon's rotation around earth ~27 days and approximately 12+ rotations in a solar year. Now earth moves a bit while moon completes it's rotation around earth. there are many more calculations. like the constellation where you see moon on full moon night the month is derived from it. you also have to consider the additional month which appears after every three years.

Answer (score 0):

The google maps rest API will give you the timezone based on the LAT/LONG, can you use that?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/